# added too much oil

Tags: oil, civic, coolant, overheating

I added too much oil to my 97 civic lx, drove it about 30 miles. It started to overheat and antifreeze started to leak from somewhere. I drained the excess oil, which looked brown, and started it and let it idle with no problem. A couple miles down the road it overheated. What should I do.

Comment: Based on how this question is being asked, my recommendation is that you take the car to a mechanic. Q&A sites are best used for answering specific questions.

Comment: Your problems didn't occur due to too much oil. There are some other major issues going on, like either a cracked block or a blown head gasket. As @Paul suggested, either get it to a mechanic for some major work, or my alternate suggestion is to take it to the bone yard and get a new car. Ultimately the choice is yours.

Comment: @lance could you lend an estimate for how much oil went over, maybe even related to the dipstick level.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a problem with your coolant system. Too much oil will simply burn off the excess oil, and you shouldn't notice much of a difference. You can get a neon liquid from most auto parts stores, pour it in your radiator, as you would coolant, not in your reservoir, unless the vehicle is made where you can only add it to the reservoir. You then use the neon liquid kit with a black light or at night, and the coolant will glow where it is leaking from. If it's close to the end of a hose, just cut it shorter. If it's over heating due to cold weather, make sure your coolant system has a good level of antifreeze, because cars will not overheat on simply water in the summer time, but in the winter it will freeze and the coolant will not move down the radiator, if it's all water, it will freeze instead of just cooling down, leaving your block with no flow of cool water. If you are in extreme temperatures, you can cover the front of the radiator with something like a piece of cardboard to keep air from moving through the radiator.